# REST Api : modeling predecessors endpoint for a resource

Tags: java, spring, rest

I struggling defining  a REST Api:

I am modeling an Api for a transaction systems: for now I have defined some endpoints for the transactions resources. My endpoints are :

```
POST 
/transactions

GET
/transactions/{id}

GET
/transactions
```

I want to add a new endpoint for getting the previous 10 transactions to a certain transaction before a certain date.

I have defined the endpoint as :

```
1.  GET
/transactions/previous10?start={TxId}&before={date}
```

Before, I wanted it define it like this :

```
2. GET
/transactions?start={TxId}&before={date}&prev=10
```

but whenever a GET on /transactions is done I have to look up for the query parameters to see if they are set or not (may be it should be done like this).

Which is more semantically correct 1, 2 or another solution ?

I am using spring boot and java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternate for the API

```
/transaction?offset={TxId}&date={date}&before=true&limit=10
```

Here

`offset` to identify the particular record

`date` is the condition date default is current date

`before` is condition default is `false`

`limit` is records count

Example

```
/transaction?offset=20&date=2017-03-21&before=true&limit=10
```

**Explanation**

In future you need `after` the particular `date` records also use simply add `after=true` and this is flexible service

**This is my understanding any changes welcome**

[Read more about REST best practices](http://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/)